# Identifying whether this JavaScript script is custom or from a jQuery library 

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've been trying to debug a site and can't figure out the script it is using.

The site is http://heydays.no/

I'm interested in the script `top-bar-view.min.js`. I know the script uses jQuery, but is it from a jQuery library or is it something the makers of the site created from scratch?

Where can I see an example if it is from a library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They made it from scratch. And did a light obfuscation (deleted whitespaces and other) to minimize code length.

Templates and other files associated with jQuery should contain the name in the file.